# Notification: Open different Activities dynamically on Android 12 - trampoline restrictions issue

Tags: android, notifications, android-12

Similar question: [Android 12 - Notification trampoline restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69238026/android-12-notification-trampoline-restrictions)

My question is slightly different from the above question because I am asking for a fundamental proper way to handle the deeplinks.

I am displaying the notification triggered by the Push notification.
If the app is Multi-Activity architecture and the app needs to open different Activity depends on the deeplink value, then there are 2 ways to handle:

1. Interpret the deeplink value first and then register the proper Activity when clicked.
2. Use a transparent dummy Activity as the destination. Have the TransparentDeeplinkHandleActivity::class.java to handle which Activity to open.

I am an SDK developer which makes it slightly more complicated. I don't know the client's destination Activity class and if they are using Multi-Activity or Single-Activiy-multi-Fragment architecture.

Solution 2 sounds a bit hacky. Should I implement the callback to ask the client-side to return the destination Activity class given the deeplink path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

I ended up choosing Solution #2, which is the hacky solution:

2. Use a transparent dummy Activity as the destination. Have the TransparentDeeplinkHandleActivity::class.java to handle which Activity to open.

The reason is that SDK needs to **send the analytics** before opening the client's  "real" Activity.

Pre-Android 12, the SDK is architected to open the BroadCastRecevier and it sends analytics. And then the BroadCastReceiver opens the Activity.

The BroadCastRecevier is now replaced with TransparentDeeplinkHandleActivity for TargetSDK >= 31

Comment: can you please elaborated more or place sample code to handle notification data payload handling on tap when application is background